# What else beyond Gosched?

Tags: go

Code snippet below,

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "runtime"
)

func main() {
        runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
        var s string
        done := make(chan bool)
        go func() {
                fmt.Scanln(&s)
                fmt.Println(s)
                done <- true
        }()

        var i int
        for i = 0; i < 1e10; i++ {
        }
        fmt.Println(i)
        <-done
}
```

Run it, quickly type a few chars e.g. `abcd` before the `for` loop ends; finally hit `Enter`. To my knowledge there is none of yield points available within the `for` loop for `Gosched` to switch the main goroutine to the subroutine, why had it *promptly* printed `abcd` even before the `for` loop was finished?

```
abcd10000000000

abcd
```

Comment: Even if the for loop can't be preempted (which could change with different Go versions), there's nothing here preventing the scan goroutine from printing before the main goroutine. (and in your example, it's not printing before that at all, the `10000000000` is obviously printed before the `abcd`

Answer (score 1):

It is random you cannot predict the output. Because in your case the go routine will run and then the for loop will execute. Now if go routine finished before the for loop completes its iterations then it will print the value inside the go routine first and send the value on `done` channel and then it will print the value of `i`. The `done` channel will wait until the value is sent on it by the go routine.

For example if you try to scan only `as` and then enter fast your value will print first inside the go routine then `10000000000` will print in the last so it depends on if go routine will execute before the for loop completes.

The runtime can allocate more threads than the value of `GOMAXPROCS` to service multiple outstanding I/O requests. `GOMAXPROCS` only affects how many goroutines can actually execute at once; arbitrarily more may be blocked in system calls.

Comment: Using `strace` I can see that more native threads are created, but don't know which one has affinity to the goroutine where `Scanln` is invoked.

Comment: @sof It actually depends on what is your thread priority. Basically Golang handles it by itself. That's why it did not assign an id to the thread on which the go routine is running. This is a good thing about go routines you need not to worry about memory locks when using go routines. So if you try to run millions of go routines you never know which is assigned to which thread and which will completes first. Since it will be managed by golang.

Answer (score 0):

Code runs as expected,

Every running program have got access to three files,`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`.

Anything you type in your terminal, is you writing to `stdin` file, and programs output is written to `stdout`.

In your case, you have written some data to `stdin`, which is being read and displayed.

In case you have written some data before even the process starts processing your input, it's the same thing, reading from file.

Basically when ever the program starts and get's enough input it proceeds, if it didn't get chance to execute, until someone reads input it's in `stdin` still.

Since `GOMAXPROCS` doesn't mean that you are going to run only one goroutine, if that is blocked a new one is created. `GOMAXPROCS` implies at any instance of time only one user thread can be running.